# Sequelize hasOne() / hasMany() and BelongsTo() duplicate the foregin key (creates new one and re-define it), and re-announce it as key

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I've been trying to use Sequelize to manage a store front mysql db.
I followed the docs here - https://sequelize.org/master/manual/assocs.html

And did (like they said)

```
const Customer = sequelize.define(
  "customers",
  {
    customer_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    first_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
      allowNull: false,
    },
    last_name: DataTypes.STRING,
  },
  { tableName: "customers" }
);

const Order = sequelize.define(
  "orders",
  {
    order_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      autoIncrement: true,
      primaryKey: true,
    },
    customer_id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      allowNull: false,
    },
  },
  { tableName: "orders" }
);
```

and then announce the foregin key like so:

```
Customer.hasMany(Order, {
  foreignKey: 'customer_id'
});
Order.belongsTo(Customer);
```

And it creates duplicate foregin key, both the customer_id I specified and customerID as the default one.
I can overcome this by also defying foreginKey option in the belongsTo tab.
But even then I get this weird behavior that every time I run the server it "adds" another, like in the picture (from heidiSQL).

[image: See 17 foregin key for the same column]

I have tried to remove the field from the define() method like @tam.teixeira suggested

And replaced the code to be:

```
Customer.hasMany(Order, { foreignKey: "customerID"});
Order.belongsTo(Customer);
```

But it still creates 2 foreginKey that way

```
[![enter code here][2]][2]
```

Comment: Same error here, do you manage to find a fix?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the definition of

```js
customer_id: {
  type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
  allowNull: false,
}
```

from the `orders` model, sequelize automatically handles that field, also since its `NOT NULL` you need to add that condition to the association :

```
Customer.hasMany(Order, {
  foreignKey: { 
     name: 'customer_id', 
     allowNull: false
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you @tam.teixeira It helps with not re-define it as foreginKey again (the 17 foreginKey example) but it still creates duplicate foreginKey if I specify the name just in one of them.